# Python + Selenium: Path to driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Is there any possibility to run Python + Selenium script without entering the path of an `exe` file in every single script in Python line:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome().
```

The same question applies to "IE Driver", "Edge Driver" and "Gecko Driver". Can it be done by some general python class and should I create some additional file for it? Or is it a matter of Integrated Development Environment configuration?

I would be grateful for your expert word.

Answer (score 3):

**No matter which OS you use** you have multiple options to achieve this.

- first of all you can put driver file (like `chromedriver.exe`) in a relative
  folder to your python files. (this is what I normally do)

`driver = webdriver.Chrome('../chromedriver.exe')`

`driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('../phantomjs.exe')`

- You can put address to `chrome driver`
  inside your `PATH` variable in Windows, Linux or ...

`driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')`

`driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs.exe')`

- Also you can set an environment variable and always rely on that.

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.environ.get('CHROME_DRIVER_PATH'))`

`driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(os.environ.get('PHANTOMJS_DRIVER_PATH'))`

Answer (score 3):

You can change the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/py). Just assign the value of `executable_path` to your chromedriver path. Let me explain -

When you "normally" type this -

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"path\chromedriver.exe")
```

The `WebDriver` object initializes in its [class](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py). The class file is located at //selenium_folder/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py. Inside it, if you notice the `__init__` method, it takes an argument of `executable_path`. So you can simply do -

```
def __init__(self, executable_path="chromedriver", port=0,
                 options=None, service_args=None,
                 desired_capabilities=None, service_log_path=None,
                 chrome_options=None):

     executable_path = "path\chromedriver.exe"
```

This way, the following code will successfully run the driver -

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to store the driver in the PATH. for example mine is at `C:\python\python(version)\lib\site-package\selenium\webdriver` and then store the driver in the proper folder. Also make sure to add the path to your machines environmental variables.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what worked for me. I put the driver file in the same folder as the app I'm coding and the line in the code looks like:

web = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')

Comment: This has already been mentioned in [Soorena's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51678318/2227743).